# Criar coluna com valor de outra coluna if conditon is TRUE

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

Estou tentando criar uma coluna x, com o valor da coluna A, se o valor da coluna B == X, se não = 0

Exemplo:

vendas<-c(100,140,200,300,20,1000,200,3000)

vendedor<-c("A","B","A","B","C","C","D","A")

regiao<-c("Norte","Sul","Leste","Norte","Sul","Norte","Leste","Sul")

df<-data.frame(vendedor,regiao,vendas)

newcol seria :
if região == 'norte' pegue o valor do vendedor, else 0

resultado

newcol = "A",0,0,"B",0,"C",0,0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `ifelse` do próprio R existe para exatamente essa situação, aplicando um if/else a um vetor de uma maneira mais compacta.

```r
#ifelse aplica um if/else a um vetor

ifelse(c(1, 0, 3) > 0, "SIM", "NÃO")
#> [1] "SIM" "NÃO" "SIM"

#aplicado nos seus dados
vendas<-c(100,140,200,300,20,1000,200,3000)

vendedor<-c("A","B","A","B","C","C","D","A")

regiao<-c("Norte","Sul","Leste","Norte","Sul","Norte","Leste","Sul")

df<-data.frame(vendedor,regiao,vendas)

df['newcol'] = ifelse(df$regiao == "Norte", df$vendedor, 0)

df
#>   vendedor regiao vendas newcol
#> 1        A  Norte    100      A
#> 2        B    Sul    140      0
#> 3        A  Leste    200      0
#> 4        B  Norte    300      B
#> 5        C    Sul     20      0
#> 6        C  Norte   1000      C
#> 7        D  Leste    200      0
#> 8        A    Sul   3000      0

#ou com o tidyverse
library(tidyverse)

df<-data.frame(vendedor,regiao,vendas)

df %>% 
  mutate(newcol = ifelse(regiao == "Norte", vendedor, 0))
#>   vendedor regiao vendas newcol
#> 1        A  Norte    100      A
#> 2        B    Sul    140      0
#> 3        A  Leste    200      0
#> 4        B  Norte    300      B
#> 5        C    Sul     20      0
#> 6        C  Norte   1000      C
#> 7        D  Leste    200      0
#> 8        A    Sul   3000      0
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Por algum motivo eu tenho o retorno de números, não do valor associado A B C ou D

df$newcol

[1] 1 0 0 2 0 3 0 0


Meus dados não são esses, mas seguem o mesmo padrão do exemplo, ficam como números e não com a string

Comment: A coluna com ABCD é um factor? Se sim usar o ifelse assim `ifelse(df$regiao == "Norte", as.character(df$vendedor), 0)` funciona. Ou `as.character(vendedor)` no exemplo com tidyverse

Comment: Acabei de entrar aqui novamente para comentar isso, a coluna estava como fator, transformei com as.character e funcionou :)
Obrigado pela ajuda!